# Apache Reverse proxy not loading entire app

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have setup Apache reverse proxy on Ubuntu 16 as i want to be able to access multiple apps from a single IP but these apps are distributed across a few different machines.

Below is my current apache conf file. The apps seem to be redirecting but not loading all of the content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

            ProxyPreserveHost On
            RewriteEngine On

            ProxyPass /projects http://x.x.x.12:zzzz/
            ProxyPassReverse /projects http://x.x.x.12:zzzz/

            ProxyPass /assets https://x.x.x.3/
            ProxyPassReverse /assets https://x.x.x.3/

            ProxyPass /support http://x.x.x.12/
            ProxyPassReverse /support http://x.x.x.12/

            ProxyPass /portainer http://x.x.3.x:yyyy/
            ProxyPassReverse /portainer http://x.x.x.12:yyyy/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Does `https://x.x.x.3/` have a valid tls certificate? Do you get the full output when requesting it with `curl https://x.x.x.3/`?

Comment: @D.Joe Will be moving that one back to port 80 once i get the proxy working so I'm not to worried about that one at the moment. It does have a valid cert from let's encrypt though.

Comment: Put your logs in debug mode `LogLevel debug` and try again.  It will show you what the proxy is doing.  "Not loading all the content" is too broad for us to help.  Are you certain your target applications do not have links to other external resources?